# Protect everything but a range for editing on user base

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I have a google spreadsheet with in the first column of the first sheet a list of e-mail-addresses (all coupled to a google-account). I managed to write a script so every user can change the values in just a small range in this sheet (actually just a few cells in his own row) .
It works, but to accomplish this, I had to give everyone in the list "edit"-rights for the spreadsheet containing the sheet, and then making sure that they only have editing rights to their own small range within the sheet in the spreadsheet.
This has some very annoying side effects:

- this way all the users can change the name of the spreadsheet itself (unwanted)
- this way all the users can edit the script code I use to accomplish
  this! (very unwanted :-)

(I tried to avoid the last point by using a library, but this isn't very straigth forward to me.)
In the end, I just want that every user has his own small editable range, without being able to change whatever else... 
It doens't seem to make much sense to be able to restrict users just to edit a small range, when this makes them able to even change the file name, no?
Is there a way to give them all just "view" rights, except for their own range?
I must be missing something obvious, probably, sorry for that :-)
Thanks for any suggestion,
Stef

Comment: not possible to do what you ask with google spreadsheets, unless users edit their ranges through a webapp.

Comment: One solution is to give each user a separate spreadsheet to edit. You won't be able to automatically update the values; however, you could set up a timed trigger to check their sheet for updates. I've found this to be one of the best ways to limit a user to the least privilege you intend to give them.

Comment: Yup, @ZigMandel is right, you can create an html+javascript based form with the same inputs as spreadsheet, put 'submit' button and on its onclick event, open a spreadsheet to edit the cells. For that you will need to link user with his row, for that, you can use Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() and input a column in spreadsheet which will list all the user's emails...Hence, mapping is done. Now, deploy the webapp as 'me' and 'Anyone even anonymous'. Hence you won't have to share the sheet at all still people will be able to modify it.

Comment: OK, many thanks. The proposed procedure is a bit beyond my skills, I'm afraid - you don't want to know how long it took me to get things working the way I described it in my orig. post :-). Maybe some day it might be possible without too much trouble in google spreadsheets, and I'll tell my students not to mess up the script nor the spreadsheet filename ...

Comment: Sorry to come back to this: is it still not possible to give a user only editor rigths to a certain range, without giving him the possibility to change the scripts or file names? If not, is there a simple example somewhere available that demonstrates the above procedure with an "html+javascript based form" as Shyam Kansagra mentions? IS this via a google form?